# Equality semantics of Numpy's dtype and aliases

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm doing some HDF writing/reading and need to account for some data type issues which aren't entirely relevant here. The short of it is that I am using a sentinel value to represent `None` in HDF files, but these sentinels are data type specific (to avoid numpy issues with array data types on replacement/write).

Anyway, I have a dict similar to this:

```
__sentinels = {
  np.float64: np.nan,
  np.uint16: np.iinfo(np.int16).min,
  np.uint32: np.iinfo(np.int32).min,
  ...
}
```

The HDF library sticks a numpy dtype on each dataset. So, I read it in and attempt the lookup... which doesn't work. I can work around it, but I'm curious as to what the intended semantics are here. Take this test case:

```
>>> np.dtype('uint') == np.uint
True
>>> x = {np.uint: 1}
>>> x[np.uint]
1
>>> x[np.dtype('uint')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: dtype('uint32')
```

So, ok, they don't hash equally (is my guess here, I'm not a pythonista really). So I try that:

```
>>> np.dtype('uint').__hash__()
-2588091675660302491
>>> np.uint.__hash__()          
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor '__hash__' of 'numpy.uint32' object needs an argument
```

ok... so I'm assuming that whatever `np.uint.__hash__` needs a `self` arg. Interestingly, it's also callable (`np.uint(1.0) -> 1`), while `np.dtype('uint')` is not.

I'm not terribly interested in tracing the source, I have other ways to do this, but I'm really curious as to what the intended semantics are here.

Comment: It looks like ``np.uint`` is a proper ``type`` – thus ``np.uint.__hash__`` is a method intended for instances *of* ``np.uint`` – whereas ``np.dtype('uint')`` is an instance of ``np.dtype`` – thus ``np.dtype('uint').__hash__`` has an instance to operate on. You need ``hash(np.uint)`` to get the hash of ``np.uint``. Either way, they're not the same and thus break the [requirement for well-behaved ``__hash__``](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: That appears to be the case, thanks! The semantics of `==` seem to strange to me here

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: I'm sure I'm missing some clas hierarchy thing or some other instance of  "python semantic I don't understand yet"

Comment: Looks like the `np.dtype` `__eq__` method can handle comparison with corresponding functions, e.g. `np.dtype('uint').__eq__(np.uint)`.  This accounts for the '==' success.  But that is not the same as `is` tests, or as you found, `dict` hashing.  I don't think I've seen anyone using `dtypes` as `dict` keys.

Comment: @hpaulj: "I don't think I've seen anyone using dtypes as dict key" probably a wise choice! I honestly didn't realize it was a type at first, my stupid mistake. I'm using dtype's now, working fine